# How do i install and run LinSSID in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I can't install LinSSID on Ubuntu 18.04. It looks like it has been installed, but it doesn't launch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LinSSID is a graphical program that displays locally receivable 802.11 wireless attach points and ad hoc networks.

To install LinSSID in Ubuntu 16.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install linssid
```

To open LinSSID search for LinSSID in the Dash and click the LinSSID icon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks worked fine 
even showing a error at the end of instalation, "libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting..."

Comment: What's wrong with your system is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/). The easy solution that sometimes works is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/1081938#1081938). Fix your broken packages is all you can do, or else give up and reinstall.